# Может ли GPS позиционирование работать в "автономном режиме"?

Tags: android, wifi, геолокация, gps, позиционирование

Хочу тестировать позиционирование только по Wi-Fi  сетям. для этого включаю "автономный режим" и GSM приемники/передатчики полностью отключаются. Получается такая ситуация: в помещении местоположение не определяется (хоть  я и подключена к Wi-Fi, но вокруг не много Wi-Fi  сетей), но в открытом  пространстве  определяется. Хочу понять позиционирование происходит с помощью GPS или по Wi-Fi сетям? Разве GPS приемники не выключаются в "автономном режиме"?

Comment: В колбэке, где получаете определившиеся координаты, в Location есть provider посмотрите от кого приходят координаты.

Comment: @YuraIvanov можете немного подробнее объяснить как можно смотреть источник координат  ? например в google maps

Comment: В google maps никак, afaik. Вы можете написать программу, в которой получать координаты. И при получении координат видеть источник, который эти координаты предоставил. Подозреваю, что в маркете опубликованы какие-то приложения для тестирования геолокации с показом источника. Мой комментарий относился к вашему вопросу с точки зрения программирования, а не использования google maps или других каких-то сторонних приложений.

Answer (score 0):

внутри помещения нужно построить карту wifi c привязкой к координатам, но так как внутри помещения плохо работает gps - эту карту гугл не построил и соответственно нет позиционирования.

У яндекса в картах видел позиционирование внутри крупных торговых центрах - там партнеры яндекса сняли обстановку с вайваем или её построили с помощью вопросов пользователям.

Если вы хотите строить навигацию чисто по вайфаю где нет других источников - нужно строить и постоянно обновлять свои тепловые вайфай карты помещения.